# 403 FORBIDDEN after a backup restore

Tags: 2010, backup

The dbas, backed up the content database from prod and then restored into dev.
When I try to access the homepage for that site collection I got a 404 FORBIDDEN with any user.

I checked the event log but didnt find anything important.
On the ULS logs, there is nothing High or critical, just verbose events.

Help please!

Comment: I am also have the same issue. that I had taken Backup from prodution and restored in dev. got the same Forbidon 403 error unable access the custom sitepages and webparts and even not able to edit default pages. quick respose appriciated... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you restore the file, set the site collection administrator for the site in the central admin and then try opening the site with that admin user.

Comment: when I try to do that, the people picker is greyed out on the page (Change site collection administrators), even if I cick on change web application, and then select the right site collection, it still is greyed out.